# How to avoid using database name in each MySql query

Tags: mysql, .net, dapper

New to MySql. In MS SQL, I can do the following query:

`select * from MyTable`

But in MySql, it forces me to specify the name of the database, such as:

`select * from MyDatabase.MyTable`

I'd like to not have to specify the database name in each of my sql statements. Can I instead force it to always use 1 database? Maybe in the connection string? I'm connecting to my DB in a .NET Core web app using Dapper, which simply requires me providing a connection string. Below is an example of my connection string:

```
server=...;uid=...;pwd=...;database=MyDatabase
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this connection string `"server=127.0.0.1;uid=root;pwd=12345;database=test"`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-connecting-connection-string.html